# Converting Image URL into Image Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to display the image into android emulator 3.1, but i'm having a problem.
I only able to display URL into ListView.
I'm using my local server, and i arleady stored the url into mysql database and pass php, but now the problem is in android.

1) I need to convert image url into image and display it into ListView including text, here my code below :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();            
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/php/ViewPro.php"); 

try{
      JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("prop");
      for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                      
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);
            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("imageColumn","Property : " + e.getString("imageColumn"));
            map.put("P_Price","Property Cost : " + e.getString("P_Price"));         
            mylist.add(map);            
      }     
}catch(JSONException e) {
      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.list_item, new String[] {"imageColumn","P_Price"}, new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

setListAdapter(adapter);
final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)       {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(ViewStock.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      }
});
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Can you edit your question so the code is properly formatted? You'll likely get a better response when people can easily read what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for :

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);      
Bitmap bitmap = null;

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(i).getContent());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem you want to display a list of images retrieved from an URL and some text.

I thing that you do not specify how to draw the image in your code. In the adapter try to Override the getView method. some thing similar to this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    ...
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.yourlinelayout, null);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_img);
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(img, url_image_link, R.drawable.default, 60000);

    return v;
}
```

UrlImageViewHelper -> it is a cool library, I have post the link at the end of the comment

What I am used to do is split this problem in 4 subproblems, If you do it once you will never have problems with adapters and listviews

**The Activity**

You need an Activity which extends ListActivity

You need to define a Layout xml with a ListView in it, It will set the listview id to @android:id/list

**Drawing each line**

You need to define a xml layout with the layout of each line (In your case image and text)

Lets define a class which will hold the info of each line, it will be called for example InfoRow (with 2 String, one is the URL other is the text)

You need to define an ArrayAdapter (for example AdapterMyInfo) of InfoRow, which will inflate the row layout xml and will draw each line

**Combine both things**

You just need to specify that the Adapter of the ListActivity is you ArrayAdapter

```
info = new ArrayList<InfoRow >();

m_adapter = new AdapterMyInfo(
                    this.getApplicationContext(),
                    info );

setListAdapter(m_adapter);
```

**Draw an Image from a URL**
Tha Last Problem... try this, It is amazing, cache and AsyncLoad. Really smooothy and profesional

https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper

Comment: The code I just supply it diplaying the text and image url in my listView and the problem I have, I want to convert that URL into a image, when i'm displaying on my listView

Comment: what about this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192128/how-to-display-picture-from-web-in-listactivity-customer-item-with-simpleadapter

Comment: Thanks for trying but I need to change my url image into image and display it into ListView